# Can't remove a linux directory using linux terminal

Tags: linux

I've been trying to remove an unwanted file: 'PycharmProjects' but I can't seem to be able to do it. Every time I use the rm command (as in rm filename) the linux terminals says this: rm: cannot remove 'PycharmProjects': Is a directory. I've also tried trying to just unistall it from files but every time I do that an error occurs. Could you please help me.

NOTE: I use chromebook

Comment: "rmdir" to the rescue :-)

Answer (score 0):

If linux says that is a directory please try to run

```
rm -d filename
```

and if not worked try next command

```
rm -r dirname
```

here also is an article about deleting files and directories in linux command line:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-files-and-directories-using-linux-command-line/

Comment: I have the same case where I can't remove a directory, everytime I tried to delete directory using  rm this message appear "directory is not empty" . But I have solved it using this command, rm -d -f -r  [directory_name] I'm actually don't know what I'm doing but I have done it. I have remove the directory.

Answer (score 0):

you would try

rm -rf "name_directory"

with rm you will use the remove command; with -r you will select anything on specified directory; and with -f you will force, omiting any rule or barrier of security so you must be careful because a rm -rf command could delete any important data from your disc so you will need admin permissions to execute that command but you will discover could be useful sometimes.

P.D. when you need help with any command you can use the man command that will show you a manual for the command selected for example in this case you can write

man rm

that will show you all the options that you can do with that command depending to the command you also can find information like the developer of the command; common structures and more interesting information.

normally the man command come preinstall in the popular distrubutions but if you type "man" and it isn´t work you could search on internet how to install the man on your linux distribution

have a nice day and welcome to linux :)

Answer (score -1):

Generally, `rmdir` is the correct way to remove a directory in Linux (and `mkdir` to create a directory). If your directly is not empty, then `rmdir` won't remote it.

The command `rm -rf <dirname>` (where "dirname" is your directory's name) is the less safe way to remove a directory and *all of its contents*. Only use it if you're *sure* that the directory doesn't contain information you want to preserve. Remember the `rm` and `rmdir` commands don't put anything in a "Recycle Bin" or similar!